# How to speed up creating video mosaic with ffmpeg

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, decoding

I'm looking to speed up ffmpeg pipeline in some way (camera configuration, different filters or any other ideas would be appreciated).

I have a device that captures videos streams and later creates mosaic video view from 4 cameras. The main issue I'm having is that it's taking too long to create mosaic video. There is no GPU on the device that could be used to accelerate the process so I'm left with camera configurations (Hikvision).

Here is what I have so far

About 160 sec on Intel J-1900:

```
- 5 min video files,
- 640*480 resolution,
- h264 encoding,
- 10 fps,
- 1024 max bitrate,
- 10 I-frame interval,
```

Command that I'm using:

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 \
   -filter_complex " \
      color=c=black:size=1280x720 [base]; \
      [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam0]; \
      [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam1]; \
      [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam2]; \
      [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam3]; \
      [base][cam0] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=0  [z1]; \
      [z1][cam1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=0  [z2]; \
      [z2][cam2] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=360  [z3]; \
      [z3][cam3] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=360 \
    " \
    -an -c:v libx264  -x264-params keyint=10 \
    -movflags faststart -preset fast -nostats -loglevel quiet -r 10.000000 mosaic.mp4
```

Thanks

Here is full output as requested

```sh
ffmpeg -y -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 \
>    -filter_complex " \
>       color=c=black:size=1280x720 [base]; \
>       [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam0]; \
>       [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam1]; \
>       [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam2]; \
>       [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam3]; \
>       [base][cam0] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=0  [z1]; \
>       [z1][cam1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=0  [z2]; \
>       [z2][cam2] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=360  [z3]; \
>       [z3][cam3] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=360 \
>     " \
>     -an -c:v libx264  -x264-params keyint=10 \
>     -movflags faststart -preset fast -nostats -r 10.000000 mosaic.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg -y -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4 -i 1578324600-1-stitched.mp4    -filter_complex " \
      color=c=black:size=1280x720 [base]; \
      [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam0]; \
      [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam1]; \
      [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam2]; \
      [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x360 [cam3]; \
      [base][cam0] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=0  [z1]; \
      [z1][cam1] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=0  [z2]; \
      [z2][cam2] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=360  [z3]; \
      [z3][cam3] overlay=shortest=1:x=640:y=360 \
    "     -an -c:v libx264  -x264-params keyint=10     -movflags faststart -preset fast -r 10.000000 mosaic.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1578324600-1-stitched.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:05:00.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 96 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x480, 95 kb/s, 10 fps, 25 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1578324600-1-stitched.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:05:00.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 96 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x480, 95 kb/s, 10 fps, 25 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1578324600-1-stitched.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:05:00.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 96 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x480, 95 kb/s, 10 fps, 25 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1578324600-1-stitched.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:05:00.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 96 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x480, 95 kb/s, 10 fps, 25 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=10 keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'mosaic.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 10 fps, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> setpts
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> setpts
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> setpts
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> setpts
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x1730600] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the filerop=4497
frame= 3002 fps= 17 q=-1.0 Lsize=   51052kB time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=1394.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=4498
video:51017kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.068308%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] frame I:301   Avg QP:15.80  size:154257
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] frame P:959   Avg QP:21.69  size:  5486
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] frame B:1742  Avg QP:22.73  size:   315
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] consecutive B-frames: 22.0%  0.0%  5.8% 72.2%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] mb I  I16..4:  9.7% 31.0% 59.4%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] mb P  I16..4:  0.6%  0.7%  0.2%  P16..4: 14.5%  2.8%  2.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:78.7%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.7%  0.3%  0.0%  direct: 1.4%  skip:95.5%  L0:25.9% L1:73.3% BI: 0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] 8x8 transform intra:31.8% inter:43.5%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 83.2% 85.2% 69.5% inter: 3.0% 6.3% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 35% 21%  8% 36%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 42% 10%  3%  2%  3%  6%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 33%  9%  6%  5%  5%  7%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 44% 29% 20%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] ref P L0: 93.8%  6.2%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] ref B L0: 91.7%  8.3%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] ref B L1: 89.3% 10.7%
[libx264 @ 0x171c9e0] kb/s:1392.16
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your command (without `-nostats -loglevel quiet`).

Comment: Check if you can use Intel QuickSync hardware acceleration. Check the following [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1428442/using-ffmpeg-to-encode-a-video-to-h264-using-intel-quicksync).

Comment: I'll try QuickSync and post the result here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.8 is ancient. Update to a modern build ([download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)) and use the [xstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack) filter. It will be faster than color + overlay.

```
-filter_complex \
  "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=iw:360[topleft]; \
   [1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=iw:360[topright]; \
   [2]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=iw:360[bottomleft]; \
   [3]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=iw:360[bottomright]; \
   [topleft][topright][bottomleft][bottomright]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0"
```

Additionally you can use a faster `-preset` such as ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster.

Comment: I was thinking about [xstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack) filter but I thought it had the same implementation. I'll try it out and post the results here. Thank you

Comment: From 19fps to 32fps (with xstack) to 94fps (with ultrafast + xstack). It's only 34sec now from 160, so far so good. Lets see if a I can get any more improvements with QuickSync

Comment: I didn't realize right away but scaling was having bigger impact than xstack. Tried almost all the scaling algorithm and I'm getting about 73fps tops. Cropping for now until there is a better option